# How to automatically make some words bold inside a block?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I have a listing block with some pseudocode, and would like to configure some words to appear as bold without having to format every occurrence of such a word inside the block.

For example, in the listing block below, I would like to configure the words "condition", "begin" and "end" to appear in bold inside the block:

```
[listing]
----
condition is_true(b1) begin
  do_this()
end
condition is_true(b2) begin
  do_that()
end
----
```

How can this be done in a simple and fast way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code snippet. Just add `sub="quotes"` and place a `*` around the text you want bold. More details can be found [here](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#applying-substitutions)

```
[listing,subs="quotes"]
----
*condition* is_true(b1) begin
  do_this()
end
condition is_true(b2) begin
  do_that()
end
----
```

Comment: That's what I want to avoid. I want to state that all `condition` should be bolded without having to go to each occurrence and put it inside \*...\*

Comment: And I want a unicorn. One text editor command will place all the necessary asterisks.

Comment: Are you using any build tools? Or just plain asciidoctor? you could search/replace in your IDE or with sed in Unix terminal.